# How do I sort this SQL-result in a way that will return the last row based on date or index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, distinct

I'm having a difficult problem. I've been searching and I don't think I have seen someone need this before.

Basically there is an "event order history" table in a database that gets updated every time someone makes a changes to an "order".

It would look something like this:

- "Order created"
- "Order updated"
- "Order in progress"
- "Order finished"

(the actual table has timestamps, eventIDs, the orderID it belongs to etc)

Now I need to make a report that shows the current(most recent) status of every order. I'm struggling with this query.
It would be easy if I could just sort by timestamp or eventID and grab the TOP 1.

But this happens a lot (because of a corporate glitch that I can't do anything about):

- "Order created"
- "Order updated"
- "Order updated"
- "Order in progress"
- "Order updated"
- "Order finished"
- "Order updated"

I need to grab only the first "updated" entry, because it's the only meaningful one. I need distinct entries while also sorting them.

But I can't sort by eventID or timestamp because the most recent entry would say "updated" even if it was actually "finished". So I would need to somehow sort by timestamp/id but then I would need to get the oldest timestamp of every distinct entry.

Is it possible?

EDIT: this is MsSql related.

Sample code that would return the current status from a specific order:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 OrderHistoryEvents.EventName
        FROM    OrderHistoryEvents
        WHERE OrderHistoryEvents.OrderID = *ORDER ID*
        ORDER BY OrderHistoryEvents.EventId DESC
```

(I use this inside a CROSS APPLY)

Comment: Add some sample table data (simplified, just enough rows), and the expected result.

Comment: Is it fair to say you always want the latest status, but if there is any 'finished' against the order, make it 'finished'? There might be many permutations that you need to define here. What if it is finished but then cancelled or returned? Is there any way a 'finished' shouldn't override?

Comment: I already filter out the cancelled ones, that information is found in another table. So I would say no, whatever comes last in this event history table would be the current status, except "updated".

Comment: If there were no glitch, where could we find an "Order updated" status? Only once per order? Always right after "Order created"? Or also after "Order in progress"?

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the superfluous entries by keeping only the first entry per order and status:

```
select orderno, status, statusdate
from
(
  select
    orderid ,
    eventname,
    eventid,
    row_number() over (partition by orderid , eventname order by eventid) as rn
  from orderhistoryevents
) marked
where rn = 1;
```

Then show the latest status per order using the same technique:

```
select orderid, eventname
from
(
  select 
    orderid , 
    eventname, 
    row_number() over (partition by orderid  order by eventid desc) as rn
  from
  (
    select
      orderid ,
      eventname,
      statusdate,
      row_number() over (partition by orderid , eventname order by eventid) as rn
    from orderhistoryevents
  ) marked
  where rn = 1
) ordered
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, we need to add one more thing: if there is a 'finished' against the orderno, then always override the status as finished (cause it might incorrectly be 'updated')

Comment: Personally I prefer using a CTE instead of a derived table as I think it looks better structured.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I understand it as: events can be stored multiple times for strange reasons and in that case we must only consider the first one. If I see "created - updated - finished - updated" then the last "updated" is not supposed to exist. If I see "created - finished - updated", however, then the last status is updated. This is how I read it, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @bhs: Yes that's a matter of personal preference. I like it better without ctes and only use them when I need a cte more than once in a query or need a recursive cte.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner This is correct. Confusingly enough "Updated" means a user has been assigned to work on the order after "Created", so the first instance of "Updated" is correct in every case. But I don't think the people working on this database communicate very well because it triggers by more than one circumstance. It triggers every time the assigned user is changed. This can be after it's finished if another user did the work. So, we only need the first one because that means it's become "active".

Thank you very much by the way. It seems to work like a charm!

Comment: ha I have a bad habit of seeing complications where there are none :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is really a fixed series, i.e. first an order gets created, then it gets updated (assigned), then it is in progess, then it is finished, it would be good to have a table representing these statuses. I am using a with clause instead here to make up such a table containing the event names and their ranks.

```
with status as
(
  select 'Order created' as eventname, 1 as eventrank
  union all
  select 'Order updated' as eventname, 2 as eventrank
  union all
  select 'Order in progress' as eventname, 3 as eventrank
  union all
  select 'Order finished' as eventname, 4 as eventrank
)
select orderid, eventname
from
(
  select 
    ohe.orderid, 
    ohe.eventname, 
    row_number() over (partition by ohe.orderid order by s.eventrank desc) as rn
  from orderhistoryevents ohe
  join status s on s.eventname = ohe.eventname
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

We take the eventname with the highest rank per order. SQL Server has no function for this (like Oracle's `KEEP LAST`), so we use `ROW_NUMBER` to rank the events per order in a subquery instead.